# How to find autoboxing?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have code that uses autoboxing a lot and it creates bugs when I, for example, change the return value of a method from int to byte, because it won't be autoboxed into a Byte anymore.

```
void addTag(String name, Object value) {...}
int /*was byte*/ getValue() {...}

addTag("Type", getValue());
```

To prevent bugs, I'm converting all these to explicit boxing, *e.g.* `new Byte(getValue())`.

In Eclipse there was a warning, but in NetBeans (We use 7.0.1) I can't find a hint for this. Does anyone have an idea how to find auto(un)boxings? It doesn't have to be a hint/warning as long as I can just find them all in an easy way.

Things I can not try:

- Use Eclipse or NetBeans plugins (I'm using secured company PCs)
- Set compiler to below 1.5 (it's not available, and would generate too much errors anyway)

Comment: Don’t use `new Byte(getValue())`. Use [`Byte.valueOf(getValue())`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#valueOf(byte)).

Answer (score 1):

Try using [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/), [Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) or [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/). There should be plugins to Netbeans available.

Comment: I can't install plugins, or anything else for that matter, on company PCs.

Comment: ask the system administrator("IT guy") to install it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getValue()` returns an `int` value while you are trying to parse it to `Byte` here. `Byte()` doesn't allow `int` input type constructor. you can add `string` and byte `only`.  This should show an error. It is better to use good IDE like IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: That's the idea. If it shows an error, I can pinpoint it and add casting.